# In-app kernel extension unloading/loading on Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt, admin, qprocess, kernel-extension

I need to unload a bunch of driver (kext) at the beginning of my Qt Desktop application on Mac OS.
I tried with QProcess, but kextunload requires to have admin privileges.
Anyone knows a workaround? Or how to start a QProcess with sudo?
I need this to be easy for the end user : one only has to enter the admin password when prompted and the application does the rest.

The problem is apple loading their own driver on a device I want to use with specific driver (FTDI232H with FT2Dxx driver).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a QProcess with root rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625870/how-to-launch-a-qprocess-with-root-rights)

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that seems to work for me :

```
QString password = "yourRootPassword"; //could be asked with QInputDialog::getText(...)
QString cmd = QString("sudo -S kextunload -b %1 > /dev/null").arg(driverName);
FILE *pipe = popen(cmd.toStdString().c_str(), "w");
if(pipe != nullptr)
{
    fprintf(pipe, "%s\n", password.toStdString().c_str());
    if (ferror(pipe))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write to pipe";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Written to pipe";
    }
}
else
{
   qDebug() << "Failed to open pipe";
}
qDebug() << "Pipe returned : " << pclose(pipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the kext you are trying to load or unload has specifically been marked as being loadable by unprivileged users, you will definitely need to have root privileges. There's a C API for loading and unloading kexts. It's defined in `<libkern/OSKext.h>`, and the functions you're after are probably:

- `OSKextCreate()`
- `OSKextLoadWithOptions()`
- `OSKextUnloadKextWithIdentifier()`

The recommended method for calling functions with elevated privileges is to install a privileged helper tool using [`SMJobBless()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html), and to launch it and communicate with it via XPC. This way, the user's admin password is only required once, during the `SMJobBless` call, and it also works for users where `sudo` doesn't work. (`sudo` only works if the user is in the `wheel` group, and only if they have a user password set.)